# File Types Question

Tags: files

Is it possible to store .obj and .dwg files and/or Unity asset bundles in a Drupal CMS?

If so, is it then possible to use API requests to upload and download these files?

Cheers

Comment: Yes and yes. Yes, to both your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The only thing you need is to properly configure the media type with file extensions

Check: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/media/creating-and-configuring-media-types